# How can I work out what a zsh command needs as input in a standardised way?

Tags: terminal, bash, zsh

I'm trying to make some sort of GUI for the zsh/bash terminal, just as a fun learning project, but most commands in zsh/bash need you to put in some sort of extra input, alongside just the command. Is there a way to get this info and parse it with any programming language, so I can get the user to give all the input needed without them needing to know how the command works (they will likely need to know a little, though)? Here's what I've found so far:

- I can get all the execs from usr/bin, and open their hex.
- I can find this location using the which command.
- I think there is a tool in the same location that can read the hex? (debinhex.pl)
- Some commands have a help command, but they all work differently.

Comment: I'm quite sure this has come up before. I didn't find a previous question though, most likely it remained unanswered and got auto-deleted.

Comment: There is no standardized way to do this. GNU tried to make access to their tools kind of uniform by allowing the option `--help` , which then prints a usage summary, but if there is a program in /usr/bin which does not follow this guideline, you are out of luck. Even worse, you are on a Mac, and the GNU tools are not installed there by default (they can be installed via homebrew), so you won't even have much success with --help either. You could of course fetch the man page, but nobody guarantees the existence of a man page for a certain program.

Comment: While there is no standard (and if there would be one, you don't know in advance which programs follow this standard), a convention is that command line tools come with a man-page. Therefore you can try a `man COMMAND`, but there is of course no guarantee for the existence of such a page. Furthermore, if you have different versions of a program on your computer, you have to make sure to call up the matching man-page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation of the various zsh/bash commands builtin the shell itself as well as of any Unix binaries residing anywhere in `PATH` can be found in the respective `man` page (so `man bash` gives you the manual page for `bash`, `man ls` gives you the manual page for `ls`). The text source of these manual pages is in `/usr/share/man` (at least for the standard set of commands) but formatted more for visual rendering than for automatic parsing (so there is no easy way to derive command options out of them). I also don't see an automated way to handle commands with conflicting options (even `rm` has those).

So you might be better off by limiting your GUI to a small set of commonly used commands, build user guidance for those and refer to the `man` pages for others.